# Opencart: change image folder

Tags: php, opencart

I've got OpenCart 1.5.5.1 and tried to change the image folder with unexpected results.

My opencart is installed on `www.example.com/opencart/`

I changed the config.php and `admin/config.php` as follows:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://example.com/opencart/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/opencart/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/image2/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/logs/');
```

When I look at the site now, all the images are gone, not broken, but gone.
After I update the folder name to "image2" the images show up broken and when I look at the Image URL I see:

```
 http://example.com/opencart/image/data/Logos/logo.png
```

So somehow it is still looking for the "image" folder.
It gets even stranger when I move the image folder outside the opencart folder, e.g. from `/home/example/public_html/opencart/image2/`  to `/home/example/public_html/image2/`

Then the image url is still:

```
example.com/opencart/image/data/Logos/logo.png
```

When I change the HTTP_SERVER line in config.php to `http://example.com/opencart2`
The images are still broken but the image url is now:

```
example.com/opencart2/image/data/Logos/logo.png
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Am I too naive thinking that the DIR_IMAGE define points to the folder where the images are?

Anyway, the reason I'm doing this is that I want two opencart shops sharing the same image folder. So:
Shop 1:

```
/home/example/public_html/opencart/
```

Shop 2:

```
/home/example/public_html/opencart2/
```

Image folder:

```
/home/example/public_html/image/
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you update the image folder path in both config files ?

Comment: Yes I did, both the config.php and admin/config.php show the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.

File 
/catalog/model/tool/image.php

Line 51 && 53 aprox:

```
return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $new_image;

return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $new_image;
```

And File

/catalog/controller/common/header.php

Line 24 && 30 Aprox

```
$this->data['icon'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_icon');
$this->data['logo'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
```

Those lines are overwritting your configuration.

You can simply replace *'image'* or do some trick to add DIR_IMAGE relevant information.

I guess in later versions they will correct this error.

regards,
Alex

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it, but I've changed to Prestashop now

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the path of in
catalog/model/tool/image.php
admin/model/tool/image.php

```
return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $new_image;
to 
return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image2/' . $new_image;
```

Answer (score 0):

no, image path is wrong!

it should be

shop1

define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/image/');

or

shop2

define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart2/image/');

Answer (score 0):

To change the image folder check that you have done these:

- set correctly `define('DIR_IMAGE', '/absolute_path/to/image_folder');` in both config.php and admin/config.php
- in opencart 1.5.6 you have to also set `define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://example.com/image_folder/');` and `define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http(s)://example.com/image_path/');`
- renamed the image folder to image_folder
- if instead you created a new folder make sure that permissions are set correctly (755 for the image_folder folder and all subfolders and 644 for image files)
- deleted the files in system/cache

Comment: Thanks I tried emptying the system cache but all still the same.

Comment: Ok, I upgraded to version 1.5.6 but still the same. Also the HTTP_IMAGE does not seem to do anything. Surely it cant be this hard.  Can anyone tell me if they can rename their image folder, update both config.php's and tell me if it works?